# Making an angular application findable on search engines

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, angular

I am developing a b2c web application on angular 15. I read on their website, however, that search engine optimization might [not work well with angular](https://angular.io/guide/universal). Is this still the case with angular 15 and google.com? What are the repercussions exactly if I do not use angular universal? Am I risking my application not being indexed(visible) on search engines at all?